# Missing required modules after installing new cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode9

I have a project that's using several custom frameworks. These custom frameworks have some pods as dependencies like Alamofire, SwiftKeychainWrapper, etc., so I have these installed in my main project.

Everything works just fine until I try to install a new pod ('RealmSwift') that a new custom framework has a dependency on. After I install it I get this error:

> diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
>   diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
>   error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

I'm able to resolve this by adding two USER_DEFINED build settings for `PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH` and `PODS_ROOT` (but why did running `pod install` change this?)

Then when I try to build, all my custom frameworks that have pods as dependencies give this error when trying to import:

> Example:
>   Missing required modules: 'Alamofire', 'SwitfKeychainWrapper', etc.

Why can't Xcode see these modules? They're exactly where they were before.

I've tried everything to resolve this. Cleaning, deleting derived data, deintegrating my pods and reinstalling all of them, editing the import paths and header search paths, nothing seems to work.

I'd be so grateful for any help!

Comment: Yes I’m using the workspace and I’ve deleted derived data several times

Comment: are you getting this error : Missing required modules: 'Alamofire'

Answer (score 2):

It seems to your pod require to update.
Please execute this command.
'pod update'

Answer (score 0):

Add `Alamofire` and `SwitfKeychainWrapper` into your `embedded libraries`. Usually this solves the problem but still if it doesn't, then try to add both of them in `Linked Framework and Libraries` as well as `embedded libraries`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. When I ran `pod install`, it was completely changing my build settings. Particularly, it was changing the path of where to find the Pods.xcconfig files.

If you go to Project (above Targets) -> Info -> Configurations you should see Debug and Release xcconfig files for Pods. If Xcode can't find these files, it won't be able to use any pods.

So my solution was to just discard all changes to my project file (where build settings are managed) after running `pod install`.